# The divergence of a function $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

By definition, if we have a function $u: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, then it's divergence is given by: $$\triangledown u = \sum^n_{i=1}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} $$
In my class sheet, there is a exercise where $u : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I should be able to calculate $\triangledown u$. How does the formula look then? Does it make any sense?

Comment: The _divergence_ is $\nabla \color{red} \cdot \vec{u}$, not $\nabla \vec{u}$ and only applies to _vector functions_. If $\vec{u} = (u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))$ then $$\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = u_{x} + v_{y} + w_{z}$$ where $u_{a}$ represents the partial derivative of $u$ with respect to the variable $a$. However, if $u : \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a _scalar_ function, then the _gradient_ $\nabla u$ is given by the vector $\nabla u = (u_{x},u_{y},u_{z})$

Comment: @Mattos And what are $u_x, u_y, u_z$ and $u_x, v_y$ and $w_z$? I don't know this notation.

Comment: As I said, $u_{x}$ is the partial derivative of the function $u$ with respect to the variable $x$ i.e $u_{x} = \partial_{x} u = \partial u/\partial x$

Comment: @Mattias Oh I see. Well you can copy your comments and put them as an answer, which I will accept!

Comment: Do you understand though that $\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$, where $u$ is a vector, and $\nabla f$, where $f$ is a scalar function, are _two different objects_?

Comment: @Mattos No, don't know what is the second object in case of a scalar function.

Comment: $$\nabla f = (\partial_{x}, \partial_{y}, \partial_{z}) f = (\partial_{x} f, \partial_{y} f, \partial_{z} f)$$ i.e the gradient of a scalar function $f$ is a _vector_ of partial derivatives. In your question, you have written the _divergence_ is $$\nabla u = \color{red} \sum \dots$$ which is _incorrect_ from what I wrote above. The expression for the divergence should be $$\nabla \color{red}\cdot u = \sum \dots$$

Comment: $$\operatorname{div} \mathbf{u} = \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) \cdot (u_x,u_y,u_z) = \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are mixing up the definition of gradient with that of divergence.

For a real-valued function $u(x,y,z)$ on $\mathbb R^3$, the gradient $\nabla u(x,y,z) $ is a vector-valued function on $\mathbb R^3$, that is, its value at a point $(x,y,z)$ is the vector

$$\nabla u(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}k$$

in $\mathbb R^3$, where each of the partial derivatives is evaluated at the point $(x,y,z)$. So in this way, you can think of the symbol $\nabla$ as being “applied” to a real-valued function $u$ to produce a vector $\nabla u$.

It turns out that the divergence can also be expressed in terms of the symbol $\nabla$. This is done by thinking of $\nabla$ as a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ , namely

$$\nabla = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial }{\partial z}k$$

Here, the symbols $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}$, and $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}$ are to be thought of as “partial derivative operators” that will get “applied” to a real-valued function, say $u(x,y,z)$, to produce the partial derivatives $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}$.

Is $\nabla$ really a vector? Strictly speaking, no, since $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}$, and $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}$ are not actual numbers. But it helps to think of $\nabla$ as a vector, especially with the divergence. The process of “applying”  $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}$ to a real-valued function $u(x,y,z)$ is normally thought as multiplying the quantities

$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)(u)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},~~\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(u)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},~~\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)(u)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$$

For this reason, $\nabla$ is often referred to as the “del operator”, since it “operates” on functions.

This is why is often convenient to write the divergence $\text{div}~ u$ as $\nabla\cdot u$, since for a vector field $$u(x,y,z)=u_1(x,y,z)i+u_2(x,y,z)j+u_3(x,y,z)k$$ the dot product of $u$ with $\nabla$ (thought of as a vector) makes sense

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot u &= \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial }{\partial z}k\right)\cdot \left(u_1(x,y,z)i+u_2(x,y,z)j+u_3(x,y,z)k\right)\\&=
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)(u_1)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(u_2)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)(u_3)\\&=
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}\\&=
\text{div }u
\end{align}

Because of this, the result of the divergence is a scalar function. In summary:

1. The gradient is what you get when you “multiply” $\nabla$ by a scalar function

$$\nabla u(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}j+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}k$$

where the result of the gradient is a vector field.  We can say that the gradient operation turns a scalar field into a vector field.

2. The divergence is what you get when you “dot” $\nabla$ with a vector field

$${\text{div }} \mathbf{u} = \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) \cdot (u_1,u_2,u_3) = \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial z}$$

where the result of the divergence is a scalar function.  We can say that the divergence operation turns a vector field into a scalar field.

Comment: +1 Good answer.